# Как прочитать многострочный csv файл, игнорируя определенные столбцы

Tags: python, csv

Есть CSV с 3 записями (50 колонок в каждой). Мне нужно при чтении "забыть" про определенные столбцы (2 и 3). Либо второй вариант - записать все 3 записи из CSV в объект/словарь и уже там удалю ненужные свойства. Сложность в том что в записях есть текст с переносами строк, так что ориентироваться на начало новой строки в качестве начала новой записи не могу. Записи начинаются с "0|127.0.0.10", но номер и адрес могут меняться, так что ориентироваться на них в решении не нужно. В дальнейшем для каждого CSV будет вычислен хэш (без ненужных колонок). Третий вариант - зная кол-во столбцов, прочитать именно это кол-во для каждой записи объекта/словаря.

```
0|127.0.0.10|1704807576|1704807627|1458209802|35205|2728260951|110|0|0|110|||||||||||||||0|||"
USER pl36
+OK
PASS 123456
+OK User successfully logged on.
"|0|||0|0|CB4C9D653A3A090000000000|5|ppc_tl36|3|0||1|1|||||||||
0|127.0.0.10|1704807576|1704807627|1458209802|35205|2728260951|110|320|130122|110|email.ru|1;2;2;2|отчет !|||||||||multipart/mixed;|Шахматка||0|||"показатели хуже средних


 

 

 

С Уважением,


"|0|||0|0|CB4C90003A090000000000|2|pl36|3|1302|mail.ru|6|1|||||||||
0|127.0.0.10|1704807576|1704807627|1458209802|35205|2728260951|110|0|0|110|||||||||||||||0||||0|||0|0|CB4C9D653C3A090000000000|7|pl36|3|0||3|1|||||||||
```

Comment: если задача разовая, то сделай вручную в том же экселе или ОО. Если хочешь написать скрипт, то в чем вопрос?

Comment: конечно не разовая, больше писать тут чем делать. Пока сделал не очень красиво, работает, может кто что грамотное подскажет. Вопрос - озвучен. В файле есть переводы строк внутри записи. Как мне получить 3 объекта/словаря из этого файла ?

Comment: Используйте модуль pandas. метод read_csv позволяет указать те столбцы, которые нужно считать, либо вы сможете удалить ненужное из готового датафрейма (что проще)

Comment: Стандартный csv.reader нормально читает такие файлы (переносы строк внутри кавычек игнорируются). `[ * csv.reader( open("test.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") , delimiter='|' ) ]`